# Why is the interaction between a c++ add-on and javascript expensive in node.js?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

**Edit** Please answer if you have knowledge of node's inner workings.

I've been really interested lately in diving into c++ add-ons for node.  I've read a lot of articles on the subject that basically state you should reduce chatter between c++ and node.  I understand that as a principle.  What I'm really looking for is the *why*.

Again, why is the interaction between a c++ add-on and javascript expensive in node.js?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to any knowledge of the inner workings of Node, but really it would boil down to this: the less stuff your code does, the faster (less expensive) it will be. Interacting with the Node API from the add-on is doing more stuff than *not* interacting with the API. For (a contrived) example, consider the difference between adding two integers in C++:

```
int sum = a + b;
```

...and evaluating an add expression in the JavaScript engine, which would involve creating a function variable, wrapping any arguments to this function, invoking the function, and unwrapping the return value.

The required wrapping/unwrapping/value conversions for C++/JS communication itself is justification enough to try to minimize the number of interactions between the two layers. Keep in mind that the C++ type system and JS type system are really different, what with JS not having ints, strings being implemented differently, objects working differently, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It probably does boil down to just that: "the less stuff your code does, the faster (less expensive) it will be".  There are probably a lot of extra calls needed to get back into javascript land from c++.  You mention though that you don't have any knowledge to the inner workings of node, which is really what I'm after.  I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: I'd suggest that your question is made more specific. The data wrapping, conversions, and general overhead in switching context is the obvious cost of the interactions, as with any interop layer. I'm not sure what additional information you hope to learn.